# Universal Path for RecycleBin (Check when modified)

Tags: c#, recycle-bin

I'm trying to make a simple program that reads when the Recycle Bin was last modified the relevant code with follow:

```
DateTime lastModifiedRB = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\$Recycle.bin");
Console.WriteLIne("Recycle Bin was last modified at: " + lastModifiedRB.ToString();
```

There is an issue with this however as the directory: C:\$Recycle.Bin does not directly open the Recycle Bin itself so the reading is invalid.

Is there a universal path I can follow that would allow the program to read the actual date modified of the Recycle Bin?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/556333/which-folder-is-recycle-bin-in-on-win7-how-to-check-files-there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed via adding

```
var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
```

At start of program, if fetches the SID of the user which then I added onto the end of the directory:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin\ + user
```